# How to join table with itself?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this menu table, this table contain menu, and its parent.

[image]

The problem is i want to get how many child each menu have. Like this,

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Comment: Will there be multiple level child menu_id(s) ? If yes, by child, you mean all the children, grand child, grand grand child and so on.. ?

Comment: @madhur Bhaiya yeah multilevel child

Comment: Please check the hierarchical recursive query link suggested.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya in the link you gave me before its explain the parent, but what i need is to get how many child each menu have, pls kindly help me :")

Answer (score 1):

If you're just interested in how many child menus are directly under a main parent menu?

Then joining those with parent_id = 0 to the childmenus, and grouping on main menus should do.

**For example:**

```
SELECT MainMenu.menu_name AS Menu, COUNT(ChildMenu.menu_id) as Child
FROM YourMenuTable AS MainMenu
LEFT JOIN YourMenuTable AS ChildMenu ON ChildMenu.parent_id = MainMenu.menu_id
WHERE MainMenu.parent_id = 0
GROUP BY MainMenu.menu_id, MainMenu.menu_name
ORDER BY MainMenu.menu_name;
```

Test on Sql Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5b2a1/8/0)